# Enter values all on one line and still be read by constructor parameters?

Tags: java, methods, split

This is the beginning of my code, I want the user to be able to enter numbers on the same line and then be transferred to the variables `x`, `y` and `z` respectively. Instead, I currently have it being read line by line after pressing enter.

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    System.out.println("Enter the sides of the triangle: ");
    x = userInput.nextInt();
    y = userInput.nextInt();
    z = userInput.nextInt();
    Triangle isos = new Triangle(x,y,z);
    Triangle equal = new Triangle(x,y,z);
    Triangle scalene = new Triangle(x,y,z);
}
```

Comment: Do you have to read from system.in? can't you get the values as command line arguments (the String[] args you get for main method)?

Comment: Did you try entering `3 4 5` and press Enter? (simple spaces between the numbers)

Answer (score 2):

From the Java Scanner doc:

> The **default whitespace delimiter** used by a scanner is as recognized by Character.isWhitespace.

Also

> **public int nextInt()**
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation nextInt(radix), where radix is the default radix of this scanner.
>
> **public int nextInt(int radix)**
>
> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.
>
> If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above then the token is converted into an int value as if by removing all locale specific prefixes, group separators, and locale specific suffixes, then mapping non-ASCII digits into ASCII digits via Character.digit, prepending a negative sign (-) if the locale specific negative prefixes and suffixes were present, and passing the resulting string to Integer.parseInt with the specified radix.

So your problem is already solved, just use the right input:

```
3 4 5<press Enter>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is using [`Scanner#useDelimeter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
scanner.useDelimeter(" ");    //Or "\\s+" for more than space
for(int i = 0; i < SOME_LENGTH; i++) 
    myNumbers[i] = scanner.nextInt(); 
}
```

---

**Edit:**

After viewing @ppeterka66 (+1) answer, see [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by
>   Character.isWhitespace.

Meaning that you can simply write the sequence, seperated by space, then simply hit "Enter".

Answer (score 1):

Take the input in String var with spaces in between

then

```
String[] tempArr = inputString.split(" ");
ArrayList<Integer> intArr = new ArrayList<Integer>():
for(String s:tempArr)
{
intArr.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

Now the integer can be used as you want it

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x,y,z;
    System.out.print("Enter x: ");
    x = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter y: ");
    y = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter z: ");
    z = userInput.nextInt();
```

Comment: It would be better, If you write something about what changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter your input data by using a delimiter such that the input is a whole string and looks like `3;7;11`

You need to inform the user about the specific input format and finally parse the input correctly like:
`System.out.println("Enter the sides of the triangle in format x;y;z ");`
`String[]inputData = userInput.nextString().split(";");`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done. May be you need some clear visibility to the user.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
int x;
int y;
int z;
System.out.println("Enter the sides of the triangle");
System.out.println("Enter X");
x = userInput.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Y");
y = userInput.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Z");
z = userInput.nextInt();
System.out.println("The inputs are [x,y,z]=["+x+","+y+","+z+"]");
```

Comment: This code snippet would behave strangely for this (completely valid) input `3 4 5` + Enter